# Add a non-editable/compact region to Jodit

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, jodit

I am trying to create a custom audio component with Jodit. So, I have designed the view for the component but I do not want the component to be taken apart by bits. So if the component has to be removed, it should remove the root and the component bits should not be editable.

Currently, you can take the view apart in bits which does not serve my purpose. So my questions are:

1. Is there a way in Jodit to lock or group a block of code together and make it uneditable in parts?
2. If that is not possible, is there a way to detect if any part is being removed? and how to remove the entire component in such a case.

These is the default design:
[image]

This is after deleting some parts:
[image]

The HTML code which i am using is similar to this:

```
<div class="audio-container">
    <audio id="audio_player" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 0; height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0" controls="controls">
        <source id="audio_player_source" src="static/sound-file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
    <div class="audio-pack" style="margin-left: auto; background: #DDD; border: 2px solid rgba(120, 255, 120, 255); width: 400px; height: 30px; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px">
        <button id="play_btn" class="audio-controls audio-play" onclick="play('audio_player')"></button>
        <button id="pause_btn" class="audio-controls audio-pause" style="display: none" onclick="pause('audio_player')"></button>
        <button id="stop_btn" class="audio-controls audio-stop" onclick="stop('audio_player')"></button>
        <div style="margin: 0 5px">00:00</div>
        <div class="audio-timeline audio-track">
            <div class="audio-playhead"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 0 5px">00:00</div>
        <div style="margin: 0 5px">Vol:</div>
        <div class="audio-timeline volume-track">
            <div class="audio-playhead" style=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using divs with position as absolute to protect some of the parts but I can easily drag to select and hit the delete/backspace key to remove parts.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stumble on the answer to this by looking through the Jodit source code for media insertion. Apparently, there is a `contenteditable` property which can be added to the root element to make it non-editable. Adding this attribute definition `contenteditable="false"` seemed to group the elements together though it created another challenge of deleting the element which did not seem to work at all. Anyway, I can do that either using MutationObserver or by adding a context menu and operating on the source html directly.